# 'S3File' object has no attribute 'forced'

Tags: python, amazon-s3, fastparquet

Trying to append a parquet file in S3 using fastparquet lib, getting below error:

File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/untitled/rough.py", line 55, in 
    write(parqKey, ws1 ,write_index=False,append=True,compression='GZIP', open_with=myopen)
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py", line 881, in write
    compression, open_with, has_nulls, append)
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py", line 735, in write_simple
    with open_with(fn, mode) as f:
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 775, in open
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 378, in _open
    autocommit=autocommit, requester_pays=requester_pays)
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1097, in **init**
    cache_type=cache_type)
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1062, in **init**
    raise NotImplementedError("File mode not supported")
NotImplementedError: File mode not supported
Exception ignored in: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1343, in **del**
    self.close()
  File "/Users/baluinfo/PycharmProjects/Dash/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1321, in close
    if not self.forced:
AttributeError: 'S3File' object has no attribute 'forced'

```
aws_id = os.environ.get("AWS_ID")
aws_secret = os.environ.get("AWS_KEY")
bucket_name1 = 'eoddb/'
object_key = 'EOD.parquet'
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, key=aws_id, secret=aws_secret)
myopen = s3.open
parqKey = bucket_name1 + object_key
write(parqKey, ws1 ,write_index=False,append=True,compression='GZIP', open_with=myopen)
```

Comment: can you add s3fs and fastparquet package versions also?

Comment: s3fs - 0.4.2 Fastparquet - 0.4.0